# How to let user know my app is not running in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

First of all, I'm new in developing iOS app and I'm using Swift.

I want to let user know that my app is running/not running in the background,
so whenever my app that is running in the background gets terminated,
the user can open the app again.

I first thought if I push a repeating local notification inside

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)
```

and then when the app is opened again cancel the notification, it would work. 
But unfortunately, I found out that applicationWillTerminate this function will not be called everytime the app is terminated.

Also, it seems not possible (as far as I know) to display an icon in the status bar when the app is running in the background. (And it seems bothersome to users to keep pushing notifications when it is kept running.)

Is there any way to let the user know the app is running in the background or not running in the background?

I'm trying to get Bluetooth signal to track the indoor position of the user (using beacons) to gather data of how users are moving inside a place. But I need to make the app keep running in the background in order to keep updating the position. Then is it possible to wake / launch my app in background when it is not running?

Comment: No Apple doesn't allow you to do this.

Comment: You're approaching this from the wrong angle - the user shouldn't have to care if your app is suspended or terminated or whatever in the background. If you need to do work in the background then there is functionality provided which will wake / launch your app if necessary. What are you actually trying to do? What is your app doing in the background?

Comment: @jrturton I'm trying to get Bluetooth signal to track the indoor position of the user (using beacons) to gather data of how users are moving inside a place. But I need to make the app keep running in the background in order to keep updating the position. Then is it possible to wake / launch my app in background when it is not running?

Comment: @user3415167 All of that information you posted in your comment belongs in your question where people will see it. Please [edit] your question to include all relevant details.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to get Bluetooth signal to track the indoor position of the user (using beacons) to gather data of how users are moving inside a place.

Your app can register to monitor for beacons while in the background, and will be launched or woken in the background whenever it detects new beacons. You'll have a short amount of time to perform updates when this happens.

See [Apple documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html) or [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/152330/ibeacon-tutorial-ios-swift) for information to get you started.

Comment: Can it only be only launched / woken whenever it detects 'new' beacons? What if the user is in the same location? I still want to keep updating the position of (x, y) coordinate of the user inside the location. And I've already registered to make the app to monitor for beacons in the background, but I'm worried that it might stop running in the background. 
Just to clarify, I'm using Estimote beacons, so sensing the Bluetooth signals are done by the Estimote SDK.